# How can I import Pentax lens information into Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, pentax

I'm trying to get up to speed with Lightroom, and noticed that there are no Pentax lenses listed under the Lens Corrections menus.

Is it possible to import the pentax lens information, even if I'm shooting jpegs most of the time?

Comment: You didn't specify version, but Pentax lens by Lightroom version can be found here: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/lens-profile-support-lightroom-4.html

Answer (score 3):

Grab the .lcp file for your lens(can be found online) and drop it into:

- C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CameraRaw\ (for PC) or
- /Users/[your username]/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CameraRaw/LensProfiles/ (for Mac)

The files are different for RAW or JPEG so just grab one for JPEG if that is what you use.

Lots more info on lens profiles can be found here: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/lens-profile-support-lightroom-4.html

Answer (score 0):

I went through this process with LR3 to use TIFF files with the Pentax profiles that I had.  This was important to me because I do a lot of processing outside of LR.

There are specific instructions to change the profile to work on files other than RAW, depending on the source of the profile (Adobe or made by someone else).

This post goes into the details: http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/printthread.php?t=176761

You'll need to change all the appearances of the following strings within the LCP files.  Luckily, these files are txt files so it's easy to change.

> a) "CameraRawProfile>True<" and replace with "CameraRawProfile>False<" if you have a downloaded or self created
> (via Adone Lens Profile Creator) correction profile.
>
> b) "CameraRawProfile="True"" and replace with "CameraRawProfile="False""
> if it is one of the Adobe delivered profiles. Please note the only
> subtle difference.

In summary, you'll need a text editor to make the change.  I used Notepad++ and made changes globally.  Now I have profiles for all my Pentax lenses to use in RAW and TIFF/JPG.